# CiviVolunteer Permissions vs CiviCore Permissions

Tags: wordpress, permissions, civivolunteer

Getting an error `CRM_Volunteer_Permission::check($permissions) should be compatible with CRM_Core_Permission::check($permissions, $contactId = NULL)` on line 151 of CRM/Volunteer/Permissions.php.  Pops up on front end Events with volunteer options and back end.

I'm at my wits end.  Followed along some other threads which seemed to be similar errors with Permissions.php but no luck.

Wordpress 5.0.3, CiviCore 5.9.1, CiviVolunteer 4.7.31-2.3.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is fixed on the latest version of CiviVolunteer. If not, try adding this patch https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/pull/477 to your ext.

There is only a single file change in the patch so you can do that manually by modifying `CRM/Volunteer/Permission.php`

Comment: Thank you!  It has corrected the issue.  I think I was being a bit impatient and needed to clear the cache one more time.  Appreciate it!